# What does http.get return and how to convert it to an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular

I have this method in my component

```
  GetInfo(id)
 {
  const data = this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "api/SampleData/EditMake/" + id);
  console.log(data);
 }
```

It just runs a http.get to a web api controller method. Which returns an object.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/[Controller]/EditMake/{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult EditMake(int id)
    {
        return Ok(_vehicleService.GetMakeById(id));
    }
```

That is the method in question.
Problem is, data isn't an object of the type which the EditMake method returns. What am i missing?

Comment: Angular will return an observable from `this.http.get()`. You either need to subscribe manually to your `GetInfo` method, or `| async` inside your template

Comment: Withtout wanting to be mean, that is the second "angular common sense" question you're asking today. Maybe you should [read the documentation](https://angular.io/docs) before using a framework ?

Comment: @trichetriche made his point. Your should first research on your own...you seem to have no idea what is happening.

Comment: I do apologize, I am reading the documentation as I'm creating the project. I will stop asking meaningless  common questions. It's just a bit difficult understanding everything and implementing it in your personal project.

Comment: @TimmyNeutron It is hard at first, but there is plenty of documentation out there, plus there are plenty of questions you can look at on stack overflow that have already solved this.

Comment: @TimmyNeutron I would suggest you follow the course provided by Angular, which is the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) and explain all the basics. After the basics, you will have more advanced guides in the sidenav, and at this point, you will have stopped asking "meaningless" questions and the concepts of Angular will be very clear to you !

Comment: Thank you @trichetriche, I will definitely take a look at that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to subscribe to the HTTP request. Http request return an observable as a response and in order to access the data, we need to subscribe to the observable.

```
  GetInfo(id) {

   let data; 

   this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "api/SampleData/EditMake/" + id).subscribe((response) => {
        data = response;
        console.log(data);

   });
 }
```